# Auto Mapper initialization issue with Asynchronous calls

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using auto mapper in my application but I'm suffering alot, I am applying the below Tier-Architecture:

1. DAL Layer (Class Library project) here I'm using Auto mapper
2. BLL Layer (Class Library project)
3. Service Layer (Web Api project)
4. Web App (Website Project)

In my we App project I'm calling the Back end (Webapi) using ajax calls and I'm calling backed more than one call in the same screen to get needed required data, And here is my issue the initialization of auto mapper sometimes works fine and in some other give me the below error:

```
Exception = AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException
Message = Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
FullText = AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping
```

I troubleshooting the issue and noticed that there is a bulk of calls goes to the back end in same time (asynchronous) and they override the initialization for each other causing the issue.

I tried many approaches to solve the issue like to merge all initialization in one class

```
public static void ConfigureEntityMapping()
{
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Notification, NotificationModel>();
        cfg.CreateMap<User, UserModel>();
        cfg.CreateMap<LK_Status, StatusModel>();
        cfg.CreateMap<CorrespondenceType, CorrespondenceTypeModel>();
        cfg.CreateMap<Correspondence, CorrespondenceModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.StatusModel, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LK_Status))
                                                            .ForMember(dest => dest.CorrespondenceTypeModel, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CorrespondenceType))
                                                            .ForMember(dest => dest.CurrentAssignedUserModel, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CurrentAssignedUser))
                                                            .ForMember(dest => dest.CheckoutByUserModel, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CheckoutByUser));
    });
}
```

but it didn't work.

here is my sample code of the invoked DAL layers

```
public static CorrespondenceModel GetByID(int ID)
{
    using (Entities db = new Entities())
    {
        var correspondence = db.Correspondences.Find(ID);
        if (correspondence != null)
        {
            AutoMapperConfiguration.ConfigureEntityMapping();
            CorrespondenceModel correspondenceModel = Mapper.Map<Correspondence, CorrespondenceModel>(correspondence);
            return correspondenceModel;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and

```
        public static List<NotificationModel> GetAllByUserID(int loggedUserID)
    {

        using (ZajelEntities db = new ZajelEntities())
        {
            List<NotificationModel> NotificationModel = new List<NotificationModel>();
            var corresondences = db.Notifications.Where(n => n.UserID == loggedUserID);
            if (corresondences != null)
            {
                AutoMapperConfiguration.ConfigureEntityMapping();
                foreach (var item in corresondences)
                {
                    NotificationModel model = Mapper.Map<Notification, NotificationModel>(item);
                    NotificationModel.Add(model);
                }

                return NotificationModel;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

What is wrong I'm doing here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should bind your global configurations, including AutoMapper configurations in an application entry point such as Global.asax's `Application_Start()` for web api. Idealy the mapper configuration will be mapped once for the application and in one place.

Comment: actually my web application doesn't reference any project in back end layer but it tried to add it in Application_Start() in Web api but the initialization didn't work across all the application. consider that i'm calling the webapi through Ajax calls

Comment: You might have to serialize access to your functionality if you are not using session state.